# What should I do to execute php scripts on my own web server?

Tags: php, c++, webserver

I want to create own web server to accept HTTP requests and send response to client.

I have idea to call PHP scripts by CLI interface but then PHP scripts executed in CLI mode. What I need do for call scripts by my own server (not in CLI mode)? Because in CLI mode some PHP abilities is disabled. Maybe I need to write own PHP SAPI?

Please help me to start.

Thanks

Comment: What abilities are disabled in CLI mode? Can't you just enable them in the CLI php.ini?

Comment: Things like sessions and `$_GET` don't work in CLI mode because they don't make sense without a web client.

Comment: The scope of the question is pretty broad. I would strongly suggest editing the question to reduce its scope to something a lot more specific. Otherwise I vote to close as too broad.

Comment: How is your question related to C++?  I don't see any C++ code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to write your own PHP SAPI, as there has already been one written specifically for interfacing with a web server. It's called [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI).

It's important to note that PHP is both extensible and embedded by design. So, while some SAPIs like the Apache 2.0 Handler (a.k.a mod_php) might be embedded in the httpd server directly, it is not typically necessary to do so in order to have the web server talk to PHP.

The difference is you still need some process to manage the underlying PHP interpreter and deal with things like recycling workers or managing the number worker processes available for the webserver to talk to. For example, [php-fpm](http://php.net/php-fpm) does this quite nicely and many people use php-fpm to manage the PHP workers and just tie that to their webservers like nginx or httpd via the fastcgi protocol. The PHP workers forked by php-fpm listen on a fastcgi socket and the webserver can freely send and receive information from and to PHP.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can call PHP by CGI by own server? What I should do for that?

Comment: Well, that's a pretty loaded question. You would need to go read the CGI spec to learn how to speak CGI.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I know what is CGI, but I don't know how I can call php by cgi by own server. Usually I execute by php clients or on CLI mode. I need information about how I should call PHP scripts using own server? For example in CLI I call it by php -f filename.php, in browser or CURL I am write web address. What I need to do in this situation?

Comment: That is the entire point of CGI. You don't call PHP yourself. Instead the webserver sends the request information to PHP *via* the CGI protocol and lets PHP handle it. This is like saying "_I know what HTTP is, but my question is how do I execute HTTP_". It's a protocol. You send the information to PHP over that CGI protocol and PHP sends the result back to the webserver.

Comment: I don't know how I can send CGI information to PHP. PHP wake up on demand and not listening some port. Can you tell me about this process if it is simple? How I can pass CGI information to PHP?   Otherwise please give me a link where I can read about that

Comment: Perhaps the confusion here is that I'm using the term _CGI_ when what I mean is _FastCGI_. You might be thinking that I'm referring to the CGI binary itself. When you use something like php-fpm (_php fork process manager_) it forks a bunch of PHP binaries for you and listens on a socket (_unix or tcp as you choose_) for requests. Those requests are sent using the [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) protocol. It then sends the response back over the same socket.

Comment: OK. How I can get socket data(IP,port) of PHP FastCGI for connect and send CGI data to PHP?

Comment: You configure php-fpm to listen on whatever socket you want. This is all in the documentation linked in the answer. Again, the scope of your question is so broad that you could literally write books about how to approach it. I would strongly suggest editing your question such that it asks something a lot more specific.

Comment: OK thank you I understand what I need do for FastCGI SAPIs.

Comment: But what I should do if I am not want use FastCGI? How I can connect web server with PHP?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use FastCGI? It's the easiest and most efficient solution the problem you describe. Otherwise, we go back to writing a book to explain how else you could approach this.

Comment: I just want write all variants

Comment: Then I suggest you head to the help center and carefully review [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as this type of question falls under "_your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”_"